# Get Eastern Time And Use In If Statement

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get and set a variable to the Eastern time zone and then use it in an "if" statement?

In one of my table I have a datetime column called gameEasternTime. Values are listed like so "2013-09-22 20:30:00"

I need to show a html div only if the Eastern time is after the time listed in my gameEasternTime column.

```
if ( $easternTime > schedule[gameEasternTime] ) {
    echo ' <div> ';
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and [DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) . Yes, those are links.